# Load font and get the characters in C#

Tags: c#, fonts, bitmap, character

I just need to know how I can load a font file and get the characters in an array of data and then call one particular character.

```
 var families = Fonts.GetFontFamilies(@"C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\Arial.TTF");
 foreach (FontFamily family in families)
 {

 }
```

Comment: What do you mean "call one particular character"? Do you mean you want to draw it onto an image?

Comment: that's right! for example i need to get character "A" as an Bitmap output.

Comment: let me make it more clear for you. i basically need to load a font (i.e. Arial) from the system and then put each character of that font in an array of data. then i need to call that particular character (i.e. "A") by referring to the array and print out the Bitmap format of that particular character.

Comment: Is this winforms, WPF, web app?

Comment: i actually need to make a CAPTCHA which runs on the web. but i decided to make it using C# as i am familiar more with C# and i think it will be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will give you the idea (untested). Take care to use `using` or explicitly dispose your graphics objects:

```
using System.Drawing; 
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
...

    // Create your bitmap - 100x100 pixels for example
        using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(100, 100))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
            {
                g.Clear(Color.White); // White background
                using (FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial"))
                {
                    using (Font font = new Font(fontFamily, 24, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
                    {
                        using (SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red)) // Red text
                        {
                            g.DrawString("A", font, solidBrush, new PointF(10, 10)); // Draw an "A" at position 10,10
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
          b.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg); // return to response, for example
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much for that. do i need to add any reference as its giving me lots of errors!

Comment: Indeed, see my update. I also show you how to send to output stream

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, that helped a lot. Could you please modify the code a bit for me as now i need to have an array of strings for example: a[] = {A,B,C,...,Z} and then randomly choose one letter (instead of giving character 'A') from the array and apply a font from the folder on it and then render that particular letter in the form of Bitmap image with specific width and heights to the user (for example in the image box in my form).

Comment: i have made anew question, here is the link, http://stackoverflow.com/q/21307644/3207537   could you please have a look?

Comment: it is giving me a error regarding 'Response': Error 1 The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Are you running this in an .aspx page?

Comment: no i put the code in my main class inside: static void Main(string[] args){}

Comment: You said you were running this on a web site. Sounds like you are trying to run this in a console app or something

Comment: yes, sorry for confusion. actually at the moment i am running on my console application but i need to put the whole application online and run it on a website later on.(is that possible to do that?) can i be in contact with you more closly so you can help me more with my application?!