# Character convert to bitmap image C#

Tags: c#, arrays, fonts, bitmap, character

I need to have an array of strings for example: `a[] = {A,B,C,...,Z}` and then randomly choose one letter from the array and apply a font from windows directory on it and then render that particular letter in the form of Bitmap image with specific width and heights to the user (for example display it as a bitmap image in the image box in my form).

Comment: Let's see what you have so far...

Comment: i actually need a code that can does this job if you can help me. thanks

Comment: @CowBoy: Which bit are you stuck on though? You need to narrow down your question to make it clear if you don't know how to choose a random item from an array, create images, put text into images, specify font sizes, output to user, etc. There are so many parts to your question that I would imagine you have at least some idea of some of them so do what you can. Post the code you have and where the gap is that is stopping you going on and we can help.

Comment: Here's the code for the image part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290322/load-font-and-get-the-characters-in-c-sharp/21290609#21290609

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey if i understand you right you need something like this:

```
//Create String-Array
string[] a = {"A", "B", "C"};

//Create a Image-Object on which we can paint
Image bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100);

//Create the Graphics-Object to paint on the Bitmap
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

//Here we get the random string
//Random.Next() gives us the next integer value
//Because we dont want to get IndexOutOfBoundException we give the Array length to the Next method
//So just the numbers from 0 - Array.Length can be choosen from Next method
string randomString = a[new Random().Next(a.Length)];

//Your custom Font (6f = 6px)!
Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 6f)

//Get the perfect Image-Size so that Image-Size = String-Size
SizeF size = g.MeasureString(randomString, myFont);
PointF rect = new PointF(size.Width, size.Height);    

//Use this to become better Text-Quality on Bitmap.
g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

//Here we draw the string on the Bitmap
g.DrawString(randomString, myFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), rect);
```

You can use the bmp object in your Program. For example:

```
picturebox.Image = bmp;
```

I hope you can understand it now :) If you have a problem to understand the Objectdesign you should read a book at first. This is for free ;) http://openbook.galileocomputing.de/visual_csharp_2012/

Dont hesitate to come in touch with me.
regards

Comment: thank you for the code i think this is the one i am looking for, could you please add some comment on the code to understand better? also does it give an out put Bitmap image and where does it display the image? does it save the image anywhere?

Comment: may i ask you what is the '6f' on the last line? and if i get it correct does this code convert for example character 'A' into bitmap file? so the bmp is a pixel black and while image?

Comment: If you create a Font object one of the possible Constructor allow you to give the Font-Name (here: "Arial") and the Font-Size (here: 6f). The f converts the 6 to float value. Same like float a = 6; The code works as follows: 1. Create a blank image 2. Find a random string from your array 3. Paint the string on the blank image

Comment: OK. thanks, so if i need a bigger character should i just put like 32f?

Comment: thank you for the book, is it not in English?! also i just waanted to ask is the out put bitmap file not a string?

Comment: Yes! I just choose 6f for example. You can use the size you need for sure :) Try it out! ;)

Comment: i need character to be in pixels so we can work with the pixels later on

Comment: Oh sorry the book is german :( I dont saw. As you say the output is a bitmap. So it cant be a string :D Thought you want an Image!?

Comment: @CowBoy i edited my post. You become an Image with is exactly sized your String. So you can size it in pixel about the 6f parameter. I hope this works for you. I dont know other solution for this goal.

Comment: thank you for that;) yes i need a bitmap file. that helped alot...

Comment: its giving me a arror for 'randomText': Error 1 The name 'randomText' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry should be named 'randomString' like the definition: string randomString = a[new Random().Next(a.Length)];  I edited post. Would be nice if you accept this as answer later :p

Comment: i have one problem with my code, the characters are appearing in the right-bottom corner of my picturebox. how can i align it in the center of my picturebox?

Comment: @sebi better to dispose of your graphics objects properly as per my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290322/load-font-and-get-the-characters-in-c-sharp/21290609#21290609

Comment: regarding your code, could you please tell me how should i save the output bitmap image to the specific folder?